# Getting an alert to display font

Tags: jquery, mobile

I would like to know how I would be able to find out what font I'm using on a phone. The reason is because the font looks different on my desktop and on my phone. So I would like to know if the phone is using the correct font.

So is there a way to alert() in Jquery to find that out?

Comment: `alert( $('body').css('font-family') )`? Use necessary element instead of `body` selector.

Comment: Such an alert, will only show you which font is specified in the style sheet, it won't tell you want font the browser is actually using. What you need is a web debugger. If the phone is an Andriod, then you can use the Chrome browser and connect it to a chrome browser on a PC. See: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging . There are similar tools for the iPhone AFAIK.